# How to get the text of /html/head/title element using Geb framework?

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, geb

Using the Page Object pattern, I'd like to implement some "at" verifications based on the text of /html/head/title element.

How do I get the text of the title?

I know Geb doesn't support XPath expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Tim_Yates is right, but you specifically asked about the Page Object model.

You setup the rules for your successful page load, like so:

```
class GoogleHomePage extends Page {
  static url = "http://google.com/"
  static at = { title == "Google" }  // the bit you asked about
}
```

Then, your actual test:

```
Browser.drive {
  to GoogleHomePage // goes to GoogleHomePage and verifies by calling at(). 
}
```

(if you don't want `at()` checking, use `via()` instead of `to()`.)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't noticed that title is a property of the Page class.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#inline_scripting) shows:

```
Browser.drive {
    go "http://google.com/ncr"

    // make sure we actually got to the page
    assert title == "Google"

    ....
```